# Image over another image although both images are bigger then the parent container

Tags: html, css

I'm currently stuck on a problem I can't fix on my own.

I've cut a image into different layers I want to overlay on a website. Basically you can enable and disable various layers.

---

An example would be this:

- Image of a tree without leaves
- Actual leaves of the tree

Now there is a checkbox and when you click on it it'll either enable or disable the leaves.

---

Now I have some options to position those elements via css:

1. Make all images the same size and fill smaller ones with transparency. Something like this: http://i.imgur.com/GRd4eaI.png
2. Crop those large images into smaller ones. Here I don't know how to position them via css properly so they'll resize with the other pictures.
3. Create a canvas and draw the image onto it, then display that canvas.

---

1. I've currently implemented this and it works like I want. Problem though is that it'll lag when using the phone (Only renders part of the image till it finally finish after ~20 seconds to display the image properly)

---

2. I guess that would be the proper way to go but my problem here is that I don't know how to set the size of the overlaying smaller images.

Html Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <img style="top:0%; left:0%;" src="img.png" />
    <img style="top:69.56%; left:26.16%;" src="smallImage.png" />
    <img src="images/null.png" id="last">
</div>
```

And the css code to that:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#container img:not(#last) {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The null image is just there that overlaying other images work with that method.

The problem I have here is now that the smaller image will be positioned correctly but it wont shrink down to the proper size inside the div: http://i.imgur.com/4EgGIAl.png

---

3. I don't think that this would be the proper way, or easy way to do it. But I guess I'll use this then when I need to.

Also I think it's good to say that I'm working with image maps and areas. So perhaps that'll make it a bit more difficult to use then.

It would be very great if you could help me here, thanks :)

Comment: If the images are taking too long to load you need to optimize them. I'd recommend using your first approach

Comment: Wrapper with position relative and images inside with position absolute top 0 left 0 should put them on top of each other.

Comment: Ah yeah. It's not the loading which is the problem since all files are around 50-100kb. it's the rendering on phones  It must takes ages that the image fully rendered.

And seahorsepip ... it's already set like that. I want to position a smaller image (which is still bigger then the canvas) over another one but on a specific coordinate ... which should also work on a responsive layout